# go to line in gedit

Tags: shortcut-keys, gedit

How can we go to a specific line in gedit? I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> but nothing shows to ask which line to go to. I found those keys in [here](http://www.keyxl.com/aaa0c32/297/Gedit-keyboard-shortcuts.htm)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, the shortcut should be specified under the "Search" menu.

It is not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, that is for opening a location. For example, one use case is when you have the "open document" dialog open, you can switch to the location bar with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (like in web browsers).

Comment: your fisrt one was true ;) ctrl + i. please edit to your fist one

Comment: Aah I see the confusion. I had capitalized "i" so that it stands out, I didn't mean to suggest using Shift. Edited the answer, thanks.